# Read a file and get the line of text Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am developing an application to perform searches inside files, I wrote the following code to do this:

```
        foreach (var file in filesInDir)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);
            for(int i=0;i<lines.Length;i++)
                if(lines[i].Contains("123456789"))
                    Console.Write("File: {0}\nLine: {1}", file.FullName, i + 1);
        }
```

So, I wonder how I can accomplish this research, using Linq, is this possible to do?

Comment: your answer is right here on this page, `Related` section there is a post already showing how to `Read TexFile using Linq`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the line along with index (line number) and then query for your string and later select the `LineNo` like:

```
var result = lines.Select((r, i) => new { line = r, index = i })
                .Where(r => r.line.Contains("123456789"))
                .Select(r => new { LineNo = r.index });
```

To display:

```
foreach(var item in result)
    Console.Write("File: {0}\nLine: {1}", file.FullName, item.LineNo);
```

**EDIT**

You can also Try the following for all the files in the directory like:

```
var result = filesInDir.Select(t => new { lines = File.ReadAllLines(t.FullName), FileName = t.Name })
           .Select((r, i) => new { line = r.lines, index = i, FileName = r.FileName })
           .Where(r => r.line.Contains("123456789"))
           .Select(r => new { FileName = r.FileName,  LineNo = r.index });
```

Then for display:

```
foreach (var item in result)
    Console.Write("File: {0}\nLine: {1}", item.FileName, item.LineNo);
```

Comment: +1. But consider using `File.ReadLines` rather than `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName).ToList();    

lines.Where(x=>x.Contains("123456790")).ToList().ForEach(x=>Console.Write("File: {0}\nLine: {1}", x.FullName, lines.IndexOf(x)));
```

Comment: Ok, but, how I can get the line Number ?

Comment: `lines.IndexOf(x)` ? too bad.

Comment: you can get the line number by doing some research and or looking up what the word `IndexOf` means..come on now..show some dang-gone `EFFORT` if you get the answers without trying how the heck are you going to support your own code `Alexandre` if you can't think for yourself..?